# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push') in spec.ts

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, httpclient

What's the problem in my code?

[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3088.png

```
enter code here
it('#getTimeSessionLogout', () => {

service.getTimeSessionLogout().subscribe(data => {
  expect(data).toEqual(response);
});

const request = httpMock.expectOne(`${environment.apiMaster}/config-system/time_session`);
expect(request.request.method).toBe('GET');

request.flush(response);
```

});

```
enter code here
getTimeSessionLogout() {
return this.httpClient.get<any>(`${environment.apiMaster}/config-system/time_session`);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

According to the logs of your provided [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3088.png), you have none in your provided code (hooray!)

But one of your tests, i.e. `MasterService's #getTimeSessionLogout`, fails :-(

Provide the code for that test and we can have a look on it.

Comment: Hello, sorry I forgot the related code:   
enter code here 
it('#getTimeSessionLogout', () => {

    service.getTimeSessionLogout().subscribe(data => {
      expect(data).toEqual(response);
    });

    const request = httpMock.expectOne(`${environment.apiMaster}/config-system/time_session`);
    expect(request.request.method).toBe('GET');

    request.flush(response);

  });

getTimeSessionLogout() {
    return this.httpClient.get<any>(`${environment.apiMaster}/config-system/time_session`);
  }
the structure is the same as I showed